# OpenCV 3.0.0 with Xcode 6.3

Tags: xcode, opencv, c++11

I'm trying to compile a simple opencv code using Xcode but I'm  getting a compilation error.

The opencv version is 3.0.0 and Xcode version is 6.3 (OS X 10.10.3)

In Xcode, Apple LLVM 6.1 Language C++ settings are:

c++ Language Dialect : `C++11[-std=c++11]`

c++ Standard Library : `libc++`

the error is:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

When I change the c++ standard library to `libstdc++`, then the error was:

`/usr/local/include/opencv2/hal/defs.h:271:14: 'cstdint' file not found`

Can someone show me how to get opencv work with Xcode?  I've already followed lot of forums and guides but still getting the same error.

Comment: did you link the highgui lib/so?

Comment: yes, I did link opencv_core, opencv_improc and opencv_highgui under other linker flags. Also I have tried linking them adding dylib file to the project. Still the issue is there..

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: This issue has been solved. What I made it to work was, set the **C++11** for C++ Language Dialect and set **libc++** for C++ Standard Library. My Xcode version is 7.1.1 and OpenCV version is 2.4.11 (installed using brew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, either I got the "Undefined symbols x86_64" with libc++, or "cstdint file not found" with libstdc++.

What finally made it work for me was that I needed to add a lot more libs than I'm used to, it wasn't enough to add just core, imgproc, and highgui for even a simple project. 
So I went to **Build Settings**, searched for **Linking**, and in **Other Linker Flags** I added the whole lot:
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0 and Xcode 6.4. C++ Standard Library set to **libc++** and C++ Language Dialect **C++11**. Hope this helps!